# angular6 and NGRX: Dispatching Load action Immediately after Save action

Tags: angular, rxjs, crud, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am saving a POJO and then pulling the POJO array from the database via rest api
I am using ngrx as the redux pattern.

```
   this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.SaveMessage(this.messageHeader));
   this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadMessages({ queue: "Queue" });
```

However the 2nd action is not pulling the recently saved message.

While I tried the below approch, it **worked**.

```
  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.SaveMessage(this.messageHeader));
    setTimeout(() => {
  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadMessages({ queue: "Queue" }));
  }, 2000)
```

However I feel this is not the most **optimized** approach.

I also tried to subscribe to the 1st dispatch action but it gave an error stating

```
 '[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.'
```

How do I send out the 2nd action dispatcher to pull even the recently saved record?

Comment: have you looked at ngrx/effects?  generally you'll want your SaveMessage to respond with a SUCCESS action, then wire an effect to do the reload, or set a piece of state you can subscribe to in your component to do the reload once the success is processed.  the first solution is preferable if you want the load to happen every time.

Comment: we are reloading it on demand ( on click of a button ) and not on the success callback of the save for a purpose. Hence the issue.

Comment: can you have your load operation watch for an 'saving' flag in your store and delay processing until the save operation completes?  e.g., if saving then subscribe to a selector on the saving flag and run the operation once it's false.

Comment: this is a good approach. Let me try this.